# document.getElementById(“ID”).focus() when focusing <object> containing swf

Tags: apache-flex

How to set focus to embedded swf object in chrome.document.getElementById(“ID”).focus() is not working in chrome but works fine with firefox and ie.

Comment: my suggestion would be to google 'swf document focus WebKit'... you'll find the same issue w/ safari and there may now exist a fix (though I'm not 100% sure).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think this worked in anything except IE.